# Can I invoke a graphical program to run with a hidden window?

Tags: metacity

I have a program that interprets the input from my mouse and provides multitouch gestures.  I wrote it using a game engine, which always creates a window when it runs. I'd like to run this program without seeing the window, so this is the point of the questions:

Can invoke a graphical program but have the window hidden?

By hidden I mean anything that keeps me from encountering the window on my desktop.  So I would accept something like, "open on a different, previously non-existant screen."

Comment: Which Desktop Environment? What language did you use to write the code?

Comment: I am interested in both Gnome and Ubuntu Unity desktop environments.  As for languages, I will accept nearly anything, as I don't mind writing a tool in one that I can invoke in another.  If you must have one, assume BASH.

Comment: Are you still looking for help with this or have you solved the problem?

Comment: I would still like to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The tool `devilspie` (available in 12.04 from repository) can act on new or already present windows, in a way at least similar to what you want.

You will need to create a configuration file, by convention something like `.devilspie/my-app.ds`. The configuration language is funky lisp-style poorly-documented abomination, but should be able to do what you want.

You need a way to (i) identify your window and (ii) decide on the action. If, for example, your window's title happened to contain "my-app" and you wanted to always put that window on 2nd workspace, this file would contain:

```
(if (contains (application_name) "my-app") (set_workspace 2))
```

Next, start it: `devilspie -a ~/.devilspie/my-app.ds`, and it should act on current and future windows (without `-a` only on future windows).

This might not be exactly what you want, for example `(minimize)` instead of `(set_workspace 2)` perhaps suits you better. The man page has a listing of all the symbols and their meanings, I hope you find a solution there.